# Application freezing while creating visual container for DataGrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on a problem that has me on it's toes for the last weeks or so.

This is not a normal freezing problem solveable by multi-threading, because I'm doing this already for the business logic.

I have a View with a DataGrid, the DataContext is a ViewModel supplying an `ObservableCollection<T>` to a `CollectionViewSource` named `iGroupingJournal`.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource iGroupedJournal}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DateTime}" Header="DateTime" />
        [...]
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Usually, about 50 rows having 7 columns are displayed, which causes the application to freeze while these rows are generated.

**I already ruled out the following as causes for this:**

1.1. complex business class producing overhead -> tested with a data holding class, produces no increase in speed

1.2. expensive database query gets executed in the gui thread due to getting the data via LINQ -> data gets fetched in the workerthread by caling `ToList` and mapping the data to the aforementioned holding classes

1.3. collection grouping increases overhead -> removed the grouping header in the `CollectionViewSource`.

**The following was tested or thought about:**

2.1. Tested UI Virtualisation by removing the grouping instruction, didn't have any effect, also grouping is a desireable feature

2.2. Data Virtualisation - won't have an effect because 50 rows have to be created as that's what usually shown

**Conclusion**

I did all I could to get the work out of the GUI thread, and it's clearly visible by a LoadingIndicator that the moment the workerthread sends `NotifyCollectionChanged` to the GUI thread, the whole application freezes. Did you encounter this problem before? How did you solve it? Or am I'm really out of luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was grouping. I thought I could just remove the groups from the `CollectionViewSource`, which wasn't the case - I needed to remove the `GroupTemplate` as well.